# Creating a nested if statement. If cells K2 or D2 have certain words in

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a formula right now that looks to cell K2 and writes the word "SKIP" in cell J2 if cell K2 is blank. Like below:

=if(ISBLANK(K2),"SKIP","")

What I want to do is add an additional check, which is, if cell D2 has the word "anonymous" in then keep the word "anonymous" in cell K2. Is this possible?

I tried this:

=if(D2="anonymous","SKIP","",if(ISBLANK(K2),"SKIP",""))

but get the error message "Wrong number of arguments to IF. Expected between 2 and 3 arguments, but received 4 arguments."

Can anyone help? Is Nested IF statements the right way to go? FYI I'm working in google sheets. Thanks.

For background, I have a google sheet that is feeding in user feedback. I am replying to these users via a mail-merge addon with different canned messages. K2 is blank until I manually categorise the feedback type which is added via data validation and until I do that I need J2 to have the word SKIP to ensure the mailmerge tool doesn't email them. Once I've categorised the row, J2 can have the word SKIP removed so that the mail merge tool can email that user. FYI another cell reads from K2 via vlookup to create canned messages. If K2 is anonymous, "SKIP" should remain.

Comment: I think that there may be some gaps in your logic.  But from what you've said, I understand the following.  You want:

1. If cell K2 is blank, make J2="SKIP".
2. If cell D2 has the word "anonymous" in it, then **keep** the word "anonymous" in cell K2.

Do mean if D2="", make K2="anonymous", replacing whatever was in K2, even if it was blank?  
 If K2 is not blank, and D2 is not ="anonymous" (D2<>"anonymous"), what should go in J2?  If you can answer these questions, we should be able to provide you a formula.  But note that to change K2, it will need a formula in it, not data

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer below if you feel it was useful to you

Comment: For background, I have a google sheet that is feeding in user feedback. I am replying to these users via a mail-merge addon with different canned messages. K2 is blank until I manually categorise the feedback type which is added via data validation and until I do that I need J2 to have the word SKIP to ensure the mailmerge tool doesn't email them. Once I've categorised the row, J2 can have the word SKIP removed so that the mail merge tool can email that user.  FYI another cell reads from K2 via vlookup to create canned messages. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please update your question to add the details from your comment to it.  And your responses to the following questions.  So K2 is a manually entered field, via data validation drop-down?  So we don't change K2 at all?  The only cell you want us to provide a formula for is the value in J2?  And J2 should be "SKIP" if K2 is blank.  What should J2 be if D2=anonymous?

Comment: Thanks for your guidance.  J2 should stay as "SKIP" if D2 is anonymous.

Answer (score 1):

**IF** statement takes only 3 parameters **(logical_expression, value_if_true, value_if_false)**.

Based on the logic you gave, there's no need to use nested **IF** since we are modifying 2 different cells.

J2 - `=iF(ISBLANK(K2),"SKIP","")`

K2 - `=IF(D2="anonymous", "anonymous", "")`

But if you mean to populate the **J2** with "*anonymous*" instead of **K2**, you can follow these steps below:

The first thing we have to check is the **D2**, if **D2** have "*anonymous*" word, we put the word "*anonymous*" regardless if **K2** is blank. Then, if **D2** is empty, we will check if **K2** is blank then put "SKIP" on it and 'blank' if not. If we will translate this into a IF Statement:

1. logical expression : `D2='anonymous'`
2. value if true : `'anonymous'`
3. value if false : `"IF(ISBLANK(K2),'SKIP', '')"`

To summarize:

`=IF(D2="anonymous","anonymous", if(ISBLANK(K2), "SKIP", ""))`

Answer (score 0):

From what you've written and added, I understand the following.  You want:

1. If cell K2 is blank, make J2="SKIP".
2. If cell D2 = "anonymous", make J2="SKIP".
3. Values in D2 and K2 are changed manually by you (using a dropdown list?)

This is possible, with the following formula in J2:

```
=IF( OR( K2="", D2="anonymous"),"SKIP","")
```

Have I misunderstood anything?

Also, you've said that there might be different words in K2 or D2.  Unless you provide us with all the possible words, and the outcomes you want in each case, we can't help you with a proper formula solution.

If you are still having issues, please share a copy of your sheet, since I am having trouble clearly understanding what you want to do.